# Como hago una condicional usando el handlebars?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, handlebars

He intentado hacer una condicional, pero parece que no te permiten hacerlo.Lo que trato de hacer en mi codigo es una paginacion, en el cual, la condicional seria que la pagina en la que estoy es la 1, que mi pagina una este desabilitada, y si no pues que me muestre las siguientes.Alguien sabe como hacer una condicional dentro del motor de plantilla handlebars ?

```
{{#if pages }}
        <nav class="">
            <ul class="pagination-menu">
                <div class="flex">
                    {{#if current == 1}}
                    <li class="disabled"><a href="/blog/1">1</a></li>
                    {{else}}
                    <li class=""><a href="/blog/1">2</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/blog/1">3</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/blog/1">4</a></li>
                    {{/if}}
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 5):

El problema es que [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) no realiza operaciones de comparación, sólo evalúa si el argumento a [`if`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) es `truthy` o `falsy`.

Una solución es registrar tu propia función [`block helper`](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals), la cual devolverá un valor `true` o `false` que Handlerbars podrá entender.

```
let current = 1; // <- Deberías realizar la asignación dinámicamente, no en la vista HTML
Handlebars.registerHelper('isCurrent', (a, opts) => {
    return a == current ? opts.fn(this) : opts.inverse(this);
});
```

Luego puedes aplicar tu `helper` al condicional de la siguiente manera:

```
{{#if pages }}
    <nav class="">
        <ul class="pagination-menu">
            <div class="flex">
                {{#each pages}}
                    {{#isCurrent this}}
                        <li class="disabled"><a href="/blog/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
                    {{else}}
                        <li class=""><a href="/blog/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
                    {{/isCurrent}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
{{/if}}
```

Puedes ver una implementación básica en el siguiente [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uasp5rmy/).

Si lo que deseas es realizar una simple comparación como lo estabas haciendo, entonces lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isEqual', (a, b, opts) => {
    return a == b ? opts.fn(this) : opts.inverse(this);
});
```

Luego en tu plantilla lo usas como lo tenías:

```
{{#if pages }}
    <nav class="">
        <ul class="pagination-menu">
            <div class="flex">
                {{#each pages}}
                    {{#isEqual this 1}}
                        <li class="disabled"><a href="/blog/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
                    {{else}}
                        <li class=""><a href="/blog/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
                    {{/isEqual}}
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </ul>
    </nav>
{{/if}}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando en el siguiente [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkgLzm7f/)

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.